# What is this BMX?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

[image: general view]

I got this bike from a friend for free. I was wondering what brand could this bike be? Has Quando Hubs, Odyssey Pedals, Kenda Tires but no logo on the actual body itself.

Comment: Probably Chinese.

Comment: The best bet is to ask your friend.

Comment: I would call the frame "orange" or perhaps "light red" depending on the lighting and the camera.  Everything else is "black"  or close to it.

Comment: My guess: it's a BMX, without brakes.

Comment: Most BMX bikes are pretty generic, and this one is about as generic as they come.  Likely the frame was produced in an unnotable factory in China and was sold under dozens of different labels.

Comment: To find a match there has to be something distinctive about the frame. It looks like the top tube and the down tube may be some shape other than round. A clearer picture, maybe a close up of the tubing and several clear pictures of the rest of the bike would allow us to see what shape the tubing is and any other distinctive features.